# For non-square $n \times m$ matrices, when will $\| A \hat x\|$ be constant for all unit vectors $\hat x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, physics, matrix-decomposition, classical-mechanics

For non-square $n \times m$ real matrices, when will $\| A \hat x\|$ be constant for all unit vectors $\hat x$?

If $A$ is square, the answer is: If and only if $$A = \lambda I Q$$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar and $Q$ an orthogonal matrix.  What about non-square matrices?

**Background & context:** This question came up while working on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083355/how-to-show-that-the-sum-of-the-squares-of-distances-from-the-vertices-of-a-cube) from Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*, I noticed that:

> Let $A$ be a $2^n \times n$ real matrix where each of the $2^n$ combinations of $\begin{bmatrix}\pm 1 & \pm 1 & \pm 1 & ...  \end{bmatrix}$ is a row of $A$.  Then $$\|A \hat x \| = 2^n$$ for all $x$.

**Proof:** Let $\sum_\pm$ denote summation over all combinations of $\pm$.  Then
$$\begin{align*}
\|A \hat x \|&= \sum_{0 < i < 2^n} (a_i \cdot x)^2 \\
&= \sum_{\pm} (\pm x_1 \pm x_2 \pm ... \pm x_n)^2 \\
&= \sum_{0 < i \leq n} 2^nx_i^2 + \sum_{0 < i < j \leq n}2^n x_i x_j  - \sum_{0 < i < j \leq n} 2
^nx_i x_j \\
&= 2^n \|\hat x\| \\ 
&= 2^n.
\end{align*}$$

This is intriguing, and prompted this question.  Does this generalize? Is it a special case of a known result?

Comment: If $\hat{x}$ is a unit vector, the answer is well-known: $\|A\hat{x}\|=c$ for all unit vectors $\hat{x}$ if and only if $A=cU$ for some matrix $U$ with orthonormal columns.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, if $A$ is square (as the OP states).  What if $A$ is not square?

Comment: $A$ doesn’t need to be square. $\|A\hat{x}\|$ is constant because $\|A\hat{x}\|^2=\hat{x}^TA^TA\hat{x}=\hat{x}^T(c^2I_m)\hat{x}=c^2$.

Comment: @user1551 What about the matrix in the OP, which does _not_ have orthonormal columns but still has this property?

Comment: That matrix is $2^{n/2}$ times a matrix with orthonormal columns, i.e., $A^TA=2^nI_n$. We don’t need $A$ to have orthonormal columns. We only need it to be a *scalar multiple* of a matrix with orthonormal columns.

Comment: @user1551 Interesting.  Short of multiplying it out, how did you see that $A$ is a scalar multiple of a matrix with orthonormal columns.

Comment: By the definition of $A$, in the $2^n\times2$ submatrix consisting of any two columns of $A$, the rows $(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ must appear the same number (namely, $2^n/4=2^{n-2}$) of times. The dot product of these two columns is therefore $2^{n-2}[(1)(1)+(1)(-1)+(-1)(1)+(-1)(-1)]=0$. Hence $A$ has mutually orthogonal columns. Clearly the columns of $A$ also have the same norm $2^{n/2}$. Hence the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $c\ge0$, the condition that $\|Au\|=c$ for every unit vector $u$ is equivalent to $u^T(A^TA-c^2I_m)u=\|Au\|^2-c^2\|u\|^2=0$ for every unit vector $u$. By the [polarisation identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity) or the parallelogram law, it is also equivalent to $v^T(A^TA-c^2I_m)u=0$ for every pair of vectors $u$ and $v$. In turn, it is equivalent to $A^TA=c^2I_m$, which means $A$ is $c$ times a matrix with orthonormal columns (i.e., the columns of $A$ are mutually orthogonal and each of them has norm $c$).

Answer (score 1):

The answer which you know for square matrices generalizes to $m\times n$ matrices under the following form:
$$A=\lambda Q$$
where $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $Q$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with orthonormal columns (i.e. whose columns are pairwise orthogonal and of norm $1$). $\lambda$ may even be chosen non-negative.

To see that this condition is necessary, assume $\|A(x)\|=\lambda$ for each unit vector $x$. If $\lambda=0$ there is nothing to prove. If $\lambda>0$, consider $Q:=A/\lambda$. Since $Q$ is isometrical, it columns $q_1,\dots,q_m$ are of norm $1$, as images of the vectors of the canonical orthonormal basis $(e_1,\dots,e_m)$ of $\Bbb R^m$. They are also pairwise orthogonal, as for $i\ne j$, $2=\|e_i+e_j\|^2=\|q_i+q_j\|^2=2+2\langle q_i,q_j\rangle$.

Conversely, this condition is sufficient, i.e. any such matrix $Q$ is isometrical, since it satisfies $\|Q(x)\|^2=\|\sum x_iq_i\|^2=\sum x_i^2=\|x\|^2$ ($\forall x\in\Bbb R^m$).